# popup user input box VSTO Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am building an Outlook addin for 2010. How do i create a popup dialog box with user input of 2 text boxes and then get those values to show in the body of my message?

Comment: Dont worry i have figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you add the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EmailHelper
{
    public partial class EmailHelperRibbon
    {
        private void EmailHelperRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Your Ribbon Works!");
            Form Form1 = new Form1();
            Form1.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This really ain't describing how to solve the question; neither how to add user entered values to the body of of a message, nor how the two text boxes are created.